# Adding background image for a div in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

```
render(){
        const { classes } = this.props;
        const { imageDescription } = this.props.imgDesc;
        const { currentIndex } = this.state;

        var fullPath = `../images/Large/${(imageDescription[currentIndex]).imagePath}.jpg`;
        console.log("Fullpath: "+fullPath);

        return (
            <div style={{ 'background-image': "url(" + require(fullPath) + ")" }}>
            </div>
```

I have a component that returns a div with a background image, but when it starts it shows an error, Cannot find module '../images/Large/homeTecno.jpg'.
But when i change the variable fullPath in the require with the output of the console.log statement it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because require is only used to import javascript entities (classes, objects, functions, ...) but not images. When setting a background image, only a string is expected, not an object. Which is why your second solution works.

Note that you can also define style properties with an object, with the properties written in camelCase.

Given that your image is accessible through `yourdomain.com/images/Large/{...}.jpg`. You should be fine doing

```
const path = (imageDescription[currentIndex]).imagePath;
const fullPath = `url(/images/Large/${path}.jpg)`;
return (
    <div style={{ backgroundImage: fullPath }} />
);
```

Or a bit quicker

```
const path = (imageDescription[currentIndex]).imagePath;
const backgroundImage = `url(/images/Large/${path}.jpg)`;
return (
    <div style={{ backgroundImage }} />
);
```

Which works because writing an object as `{ object }` is equivalent to writting `{ object: object }`

Comment: Thank you @Kishlin. I created the project using webpack so I think I can't directly refer the image path I need to use require statement.

Comment: Webpack does not handle images. Only the client browser will have to go and get the image based on the path you provide. This works just like a <img /> tag , or a link to a stylesheet or javascript file, in html.

Comment: Thank you, here is how it works I just cut and paste the images folder from the src folder into the dist folder(public).

Comment: You should not do that, as you're testing your app from the root folder. If you move the images, their path will start with 'dist' and you won't be able to access them in development. You should keep the images folder in your root directory. In production, when deploying your app, you will separately upload the content of the images folder in the same directory as the content of the dist folder.